# AspNetCoreGeneratedDocument - On build server this doesnt get included in the DLL

Tags: jenkins, razor, msbuild, .net-6.0

With .Net 6, razor views are compiledinto the main DLL, under the namespace AspNetCoreGeneratedDocument. I have a solution where this works perfectly well locally, but when building from Jenkins, these are not included in the DLL. Based on some internet research, I have included the NuGet package Microsoft.Net.Compilers.Toolset but the issue is still happening. It must have to do with the way I am calling the build from Jenkins, but I cant figure out what.

Here is my MSBuild statement for Jenkins:

```
${tool params.MSBuildTool}MSBuild.exe\" 
        ${WORKSPACE}\\${params.MSBuildFile} 
        /p:WebPublishMethod=MSDeploy 
        /p:Configuration=${params.Configuration} 
        /p:ProjectName=${params.Project}
        /p:PublishProfileRootFolder=${WORKSPACE}\\${params.WebsiteFolder}\\Properties\\PublishProfiles 
        /p:DeployOnBuild=True 
        /p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=true 
        /p:PublishProfile=${params.PublishProfile} 
        /p:WebDeployUser=${WebDeployUser} 
        /p:Password=${WebDeployPass}  
        /p:IgnoreDatabaseSettingOutOfSync=True 
        /p:EnableMSDeployAppOffline=true
```